# Formula in Totals in a sharepoint view

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am struggling with an issue in Sharepoint: I need to display on a 'totals' row some information based on other automatic totals. There is not a formula for this, unfortunately. Ah, and these calculated totals must be consistent with their respective calculated columns.

It's complicated to explain in words, so let me explain by using an example:

Let's say I have columns A, B and C which are regular "number" columns and contain integer numbers.

A and B will always contain numbers between 0 and C.

Column D contains a percentage of A related to C and Column E contains a percentage of B related to C as well (same kind of formula).

D = (C-A)/C     and     E = (C-B)/C

See the example below which represents one row of data:
D and E are calculated columns:

```
A    B    C    D        E
0    13   57   100.0%   77.19%
```

Now I have multiple rows with this kind of data and I need to perform the calculation for D and E on the TOTAL of A, B and C. See below:

```
 A    B     C     D        E
 0   13    57   100.00%   77,19%  <= DATA ITEM
 1    4    54    98.15%   92.59%  <= DATA ITEM
23    5    39    41.03%   87.18%  <= DATA ITEM
32   11    65    50.77%   83.08%  <= DATA ITEM
56   33   215    73.95%   84.65%  <=== TOTALS
```

The totals for A, B and C are automatically calculated by Sharepoint in "Totals", in a view, but I need to show the values of the calculation for "D" and "E" as well. These are meant to refer to the Sums for A, B and C mentioned above.

So it's not a "simple matter" of adding up calculated columns, I need to execute a custom formula in the totals.

Any ideas??? Thanks!!
I am using Sharepoint 2010.

Paolo

Answer (score 1):

use javascript/jquery .. list is displayed as a simple html table, and totals is a separate row... so you can get this row, get all required sums in cells A,B,C and calculate your persentage.. then just append your D and E cells .

do you need an example? (I don't have it, will need to write one :))

Regards,
Andrey.